# Create a matrix using the common information in two lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sum

I have two large lists in the same structure of the toy examples shown in this question.

dput(head(list1)):

```
list(FEB_GAMES = c(GAME1 = c("Stan", "Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", 
"Butters"), GAME2 = c("Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters")), 
MAR_GAMES = c(GAME3 = c("Stan", "Kenny", "Cartman", "Butters"
), GAME4 = c("Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters")))
```

dput(head(list2)):

```
list(first = c("Stan", "Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters", 
"Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters"), second = c("Stan", "Kenny", 
"Cartman", "Wendy", "Ike"), third = c("Randy", "Randy", "Randy", 
"Randy"))
```

---

I would like to turn these two lists into one large data.frame/ matrix. The rownames would be from list1 (GAME1, GAME2, GAME3, GAME4). The colnames would be the list names of list 2 (first, second, third). The information in the matrix would be an integer which refers to the number of times a common character is found in both list. e.g. GAME1xfirst contains 9 common characters, while GAME1xthird contains 0.

---

The output would look like this:

```
        first  second  third
GAME1   9      3       0
GAME2   8      2       0
GAME3   8      3       0
GAME4   8      2       0
```

So the values in [1,1] would be the sum of the times a common character is found in both the GAME1 list from list 1 and the first list found in list2.

Note. Lists in both list 1 and list 2 have varying numbers of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ...

```
sapply(l2, function(x) {
  sapply(unlist(l1, recursive = FALSE), function(y) sum(x %in% y))
})
#                 first second third
# FEB_games.GAME1     9      3     0
# FEB_games.GAME2     8      2     0
# MAR_games.GAME3     7      3     0
# MAR_games.GAME4     8      2     0
```

Might not be not the most efficient approach, though.

Comment: This method worked. The tidyverse answer above was significantly faster. Cheers.

Comment: I have edited the input of the question and was curious how this code could be changed to perform the same function. Instead of the first list being data frames nested within a list of lists, it is now, more simply, a list of nested dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to first flatten out the 'list1', do a `merge` after converting to `data.frame` and then do the `table`

```
list1a <- do.call(c, list1)
names(list1a) <- sub(".*\\.", "", names(list1a))
out <- table(merge(stack(list1a), stack(list2), by = 'values')[-1])
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
out
#      first second third
#GAME1     9      3     0
#GAME2     8      2     0
#GAME3     7      3     0
#GAME4     8      2     0
```

---

We can also do this in `tidyverse` using the same logic

```
library(tidyverse)
list1 %>% 
    flatten %>% 
    enframe %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    full_join(list2 %>% 
                enframe %>%
                unnest, by = 'value') %>% 
    select(-value) %>% 
    count(name.x, name.y) %>% 
    spread(name.y, n, fill = 0) %>%
    filter(!is.na(name.x))
# A tibble: 4 x 4   
#  name.x first second third
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 GAME1      9      3     0
#2 GAME2      8      2     0
#3 GAME3      7      3     0
#4 GAME4      8      2     0
```

#### data

```
list1 <- list(FEB_games = list(GAME1 = c("Stan", "Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", 
"Butters"), GAME2 = c("Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters")), 
MAR_games = list(GAME3 = c("Stan", "Kenny", "Cartman", "Butters"
), GAME4 = c("Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters")))

list2 <- list(first = c("Stan", "Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters", 
 "Kenny", "Cartman", "Kyle", "Butters"), second = c("Stan", "Kenny", 
 "Cartman", "Wendy", "Ike"), third = c("Randy", "Randy", "Randy", 
"Randy"))
```

Comment: Getting an error at the first step. in: list1a <- do.call(c, list1). out: Error in do.call(c, list1) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string.

Comment: If you have already defined `c` as some object identifier, place it inside quotes `do.call("c"` or use backquotes

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by object identifier. Is it a character that we are looking for or a function?

Comment: @Krutik  I meant if you created an object like `c <- 1:5` or something like that, it could have an issue.  Anyway, the solution is based on your `dput`, so the structure wouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Krutik  Can you try the first method with the data in my post i.e only the head, just curious why it got error

Comment: I think the error occurred because I do not have a c variable. When I tried it as list1a <- do.call(cbind, list1) the head(list1a) is   
 FEB_games   MAR_games  
GAME1 Character,5 Character,4
GAME2 Character,4 Character,4

Comment: @Krutik  `c` is a function name -it concatenates, i.e. `c(1, 3, 5)`, here we are doing the same to concatenate the `list` elements for flattening

Comment: I see. I tried this on another list and the output is still Error in do.call(c, list1) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string. But cbind, list, rbind work.... I think the issue is with the c function. But I am honestly not sure why.